# Actions after a successful celery task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am using flask and celery in order to perform a long ML task in the background. After the tasks are complete they return JSON. I need a way to trigger another function after the task is successful... I have looked through the Celery documentation, but either I missed something or there isn't an inbuilt function to do this. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am using the apply_async function to start the tasks.

Comment: You missed something and its name is `chord` or `chain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need can be accomplished using the [Chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) primitive.